# Convert string from one encoding to another

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

I have generated an xml document as a text file that states that it should be encoded as `UTF-8`. When I check for compliance with the schema it reports that there is an illegal character in the file.

```
An invalid character was found in text content.
```

The suspect character has the one byte value of `0x92`.

In visual basic, I am using the variable `dom` of type `DOMDocument60`; and do the following

```
Set nod = dom.createElement("dc.description")
nod.text = Trim$(Nz(rs!mDescription, ""))
```

This is the source of the error. I have a feeling that I need to do a character set conversion to properly encode the suspect character into utf-8.

The specific questions I have are:

1) What character set is my starting point? The string is comming from an access-2010 database (Memo type)

2) How do I convert it to `UTF-8`?

I'm at a loss on how to do this. I'm not very familiar with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character causing you grief is known as a smart quote or curly quote. It looks like this: ’

This problem is not really Access related other than the fact that you have to find a way in Access/VBA to deal with it. For whatever reason, your XML contains invalid XML characters.

I can think of two options. The first option is to replace the character with the standard non-smart quote. Here's some non-elegant code to quickly replace all of the four different possible smart quotes at once:

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(MyString, Chr(147), Chr(34)), Chr(148), Chr(34)), Chr(145), Chr(39)), Chr(146), Chr(39))
```

The second option is replace the offending characters, assuming you actually want them, with the appropriate XML/HTML character code which, for the specific character you're having problems with, is:

```
&#146;
```

You might consider running your replace on the incoming data so that it's stored with valid characters from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks HK1. I used you second suggestion. I also had a few other characters not part of `UTF-8` and converted them appropriately. Thanks for looking past what I though was the problem. Very helpful.